# Virus guards quarantines my python exe file?

Tags: python, py2exe, malware

I created a simple web crawler using python. It worked fine and then I compiled it using `auto-py-to-exe` which uses pyinstaller. After it was converted my virus guard AVG quarantines my exe file. It says that my file is infected with something called `Malware-Gen:32`.

My program just access internet and some files.

Please tell me why and give me the solution for this.

Comment: https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/2501#issuecomment-286230354

Comment: It's getting picked up by the antivirus's heuristic scan as "Malware" (it's doing something we consider "bad"), Gen "Generic" (we don't know what it is), 32 (32 bit system).